# Subtract a public in in a switch

Tags: c#

Trying to learn c# and i stumbeled upon this VendingMachine Problem.

This is what i got so far.

```
class VendingMachine
{
    public int Coke = 20;
    public int Beer = 20;
    public int LemonLime = 20;
    public int Grape = 20;
    public int CreamSoda = 20;

    public void VmContent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Choose a Drink.");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Coke - $1.00\n" +
                          "2. Beer - $1.00\n" +
                          "3. Lemon Lime - $1.00\n" +
                          "4. Grape - $1.50\n" +
                          "5. Cream Soda - $1.50\n");
    }

    public void Math()
    {
        var input = Console.ReadKey();

        switch (input.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.D1:
                var i = Beer - 1;
                i = Beer;
                Console.WriteLine("You Got a Coke");
                Console.WriteLine($"Total Coke Left: {i}");
                break;

        }
    }

}
```

I'm just trying to figure out how to subtract from the Total of each Content.
 And what i got there in the switch.
doesn't really work.

Comment: Define "doesn't really work".

Comment: I'm guessing your problem has something to do with the fact that you're declaring `var i = Beer - 1;` and then immediately setting it to `i = Beer` therefore undoing the `- 1`.

Comment: Your switch code decrements the beer variable and tells you that you drank a coke. Sounds like a good guy to have around when your partner is in the bar with you, but I'm sure it's not what you intended.

Comment: After saying that `i = Beer-1` you set `i = Beer`. Also, the WriteLine is about a Coke when you "drank" a Beer.

Comment: @DavidG - It doesn't actually decrement beer either, sounds like a good bar to be in with an unlimited supply

Comment: @Sayse Free beer for everyone!

Comment: Okay yeah setting i back to default was my mistake. Sorry thx for the fix. If anyone can comment the answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Setting it back is not an issue as `i` is useless. It's a copy of the stock . while the initial stock didnt change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to subtract from the main variable, like this:

```
Coke--; //Or Coke = Coke - 1;
Console.WriteLine("You Got a Coke");
Console.WriteLine($"Total Coke Left: {Coke}");
break;
```

Comment: Or simply `Console.WriteLine($"Total Coke Left: {--Coke}");`

Answer (score -1):

Your calculation

```
var i = Beer - 1;
```

is immediatly overwritten with :

```
i = Beer;
```

So you can't get the result anywhere.

Comment: Indeed! We ordered Beer, but got Coke!

Comment: In fact, the orignal code makes sense : if you order a beer, the number of coke isn't decremented!